# Facebook share button not getting the current location

Tags: jquery, html, facebook

Here i have added the facebook share button on my web page. when i click on the share page i want to share the particular page on my facebook wall.i have added `data-href=window.location` but i am not able to get the current location URL.

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="window.location" data-layout="button"></div>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
      </script>
```

how can i solve this?

Comment: Because "window.location" is just a string which won't be automatically interpreted by the browser to be replaced with the actual value of the `window`s `location` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in the document ready:

```
$('.fb-share-button').attr('data-href', window.location.href);
```

or

```
$('.fb-share-button').data('href', window.location.href);
```

```js
$('.fb-share-button').attr('data-href', window.location.href).html(function() {
  return $(this).data('href')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fb-share-button">fb-share-button</div>
```

Comment: `.data("href", window.location.href)`

Comment: @Andreas that would also work. but this won't be visible while inspection i guess visually.